# Fill dates in R by adding days instead of repeating the same value

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this where the current date value is the starting date of an event and is repeated for each round.

| Event ID | Round | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 2010-01-10 |
| 101 | 2 | 2010-01-10 |
| 101 | 3 | 2010-01-10 |
| 101 | 4 | 2010-01-10 |
| 102 | 1 | 2010-01-17 |
| 102 | 2 | 2010-01-17 |
| 102 | 3 | 2010-01-17 |
| 102 | 4 | 2010-01-17 |

This is my desired output:

| Event ID | Round | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 2010-01-10 |
| 101 | 2 | 2010-01-11 |
| 101 | 3 | 2010-01-12 |
| 101 | 4 | 2010-01-13 |
| 102 | 1 | 2010-01-17 |
| 102 | 2 | 2010-01-18 |
| 102 | 3 | 2010-01-19 |
| 102 | 4 | 2010-01-20 |

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `seq`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(EventID) %>%
  mutate(Date = seq(first(Date), length.out = n(), by = "1 day")) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  EventID Round Date      
    <int> <int> <date>    
1     101     1 2010-01-10
2     101     2 2010-01-11
3     101     3 2010-01-12
4     101     4 2010-01-13
5     102     1 2010-01-17
6     102     2 2010-01-18
7     102     3 2010-01-19
8     102     4 2010-01-20
```

---

Or add with `row_number`

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(EventID) %>%
   mutate(Date = first(Date) + row_number() - 1) %>% 
   ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(EventID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 
102L, 102L), Round = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Date = structure(c(14619, 
14619, 14619, 14619, 14626, 14626, 14626, 14626), class = "Date")), 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! The first() function is the piece that I was missing. Thanks for the help!